# RegEx to extract File Name from Query String

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
Regex: (?<=^FN=).+?(?=&.+?$)
```

I tried with the quote (?<=^"FN=").+?(?="&".+?$) or single quote but still no good.

https://portal-gamma.myColgate.com/sites/ENG/Pages/r.aspx?RT=Modify Support&Element=Business Direct&SE=Chain Supply&FN=Freight Forwarder Standard Operating Procedure - United Kingdom.pdf&DocID=400

I am using `(?<=^FN=).+?(?=&.+?$)` to retrieve everything after FN= and before the &DocID. the final result should be Freight Forwarder Standard Operating Procedure - United Kingdom.pdf

Comment: This looks to me like totally out of scope for regex. I would simply use a query string splitting library and access the value behind „FN“. Or do a split by yourself at „&“.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example string, you could remove the `^` like:

[`(?<=FN=).+?(?=&.+?$)`](https://regex101.com/r/33BiQU/1)

`^` means assert the position at start of the string.

For this example, you could also write this as:

[`(?<=FN=)[^&]+`](https://regex101.com/r/uIORIF/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=`  Positive lookbehind that asserts what is before

  - `FN=`  Match FN#
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[^&]+` Negated character set that matches not an ampersand one or more times

Comment: Only problem is that the `FN` parameter can not come last in the query string now. [**This edit**](https://regex101.com/r/33BiQU/2) fixes that problem.

Comment: @24KGold I have updated my answer. You could use for example [`(?<=FN=)[^&]+`](https://regex101.com/r/uIORIF/1) which will match not an ampersand `&`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank Jeffrey Westerkamp

Comment: WOW. the 2nd expression is as good as first one. Thanks for the bonus code. You rock....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regex, you could use the "proper" way of parsing the URI and the query string:

```
Imports System.Web

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim u = New Uri("https://portal-gamma.myColgate.com/sites/ENG/Pages/r.aspx?RT=Modify Support&Element=Business Direct&SE=Chain Supply&FN=Freight Forwarder Standard Operating Procedure - United Kingdom.pdf&DocID=400")
        Dim parts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(u.Query)
        Console.WriteLine(parts("FN"))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> Freight Forwarder Standard Operating Procedure - United Kingdom.pdf

You will need to add a reference in the project to System.Web if there isn't one already.

Comment: Thanks but i really needed one liner like Jeffrey suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: @24KGold You can make it into one-liner, or for better readability make it into a function. It has the advantage that if any characters have been encoded (e.g. %20 for a space) then they will be decoded for you.